# Por que esse resultado curl_init php entra em false?

Tags: php, libcurl, resultset

Tenho o seguinte script:

```
...    
$fields = http_build_query($data);
$post = curl_init();

$url = $url . '?' . $fields;
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

$result = curl_exec($post);

if ($result == false) {
    echo('Curl error: ' . curl_error($post));
}
var_dump($result);

curl_close($post);
```

Coloquei o var_dump pra ver o resultado de $result.
O resultado é bool(true)

Acontece que ele entra na linha echo

Lá no servidor que recebe a requisição ocorre  tudo certo, por isso o resultado é true, mas ele insiste em entrar na linha echo

Comment: Já experimentaste fazer o cast atrás? if ( (bool)$result == false ){ ... }

Comment: Foi uma das primeiras coisas que fiz... mas não deu certo

Comment: E assim? if( $result === false )

Comment: Me perdoem pessoal, o script esta correto, o que acontece é que no REST não está no manual que ele me retornaria uma mensagem mesmo a resposta sendo true... eu esperava que não viesse resposta string somente true tipo booleano, o que faço excluo a pergunta?